# How to create these Feynman diagrams with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I looked through the examples of building Feynman diagrams with TikZ, however I am still struggling to build them. Could you please help me with it?
I have attached the picture of desired diagrams here.
[image: FeynmanDiagrams]

Comment: Did you look in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) of `tikz-feynman`? There are many examples, some of which are similar to the diagrams you want to create. Were you able to try something? If you did, you should add your code to your question.

Comment: @Vincent yes, I looked into it and tried, however since it did not work AT ALL, I just deleted the code. I don't think it could be of any use anyway.. The most WANTED diagrams are (a) and (d) though...

Comment: It's not a question of laziness but to create your code takes a lot of time and patience. I hope you will take a starting point from the very talented @Vincent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are reproductions of the diagrams (a) and (d), since you said they were the most important to you. I think this should also be enough to get you started on the others, since the code is rather explicit, especially when the vertices are placed manually.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex at (0, 1) (i1) {\(g\)};
        \vertex at (0,-1) (i2) {\(g\)};
        \vertex at (2, 1) (a);
        \vertex at (2,-1) (b);
        \vertex at (3.5, 0) (c);
        \vertex at (5, 0) (f);
        \vertex at (2.5,0) () {\(t\)};
        \vertex[red] at (4.7,.3) () {\(H\)};
        \diagram*{
            (i1) -- [gluon] (a),
            (i2) -- [gluon] (b),
            (a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (c) -- [fermion] (a),
            (c) -- [scalar, red] (f),
        };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{3}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex at (0, 1) (i1) {\(g\)};
        \vertex at (0,-1) (i2) {\(g\)};
        \vertex at (2, 1) (a);
        \vertex at (2,-1) (b);
        \vertex at (4, 1) (f1) {\(t\)};
        \vertex at (4,-1) (f2) {\(\bar{t}\)};
        \vertex at (2,0) (c);
        \vertex[red] at (4,0) (f3) {\(H\)};
    \diagram*{
        (i1) -- [gluon] (a) -- [fermion] (f1),
        (i2) -- [gluon] (b) -- [anti fermion] (f2),
        (a) -- [fermion] (b),
        (c) -- [scalar, red] (f3);
    };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome! I was able to produce other diagrams as well. Thank you, it was very helpful !

Comment: Very kind Vincent I think that the coils are in another verse. Look the first picture.

Answer (score 3):

As a model, I propose a simple `pstricks` code for the first image:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-feyn, pst-node, pst-arrow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(4,2)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed, linecolor=red](2,0)(4,0)
    \uput[ul](4,0){$\color{red}H$}
    \psset{windings=6, amplitude=3mm, linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.12}
    \psGluon(-2,-1)(0,-1)\uput[l](-2,-1){$g$}
    \psGluon(-2,1)(0,1)\uput[l](-2,1){$g$}
    \psset{ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.55}
    \pspolygon (0,1)(0,-1)(2,0)
    \uput[l](1,0){$t$}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]